# ASUS USB-AC56 (rtl8812au) WiFi Range issues

Tags: wireless, usb, asus, adapter, realtek-wireless

I'm trying to install my ASUS USB-AC56 wireless adapter on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and I've tried every solution posted on forums, but still suffer from range issues.

The output from the terminal command `usb-devices | awk '/17d2/' RS=` follows:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0b05 ProdID=17d2 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=123456
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8812au
```

Anyone that has a fix?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `usb-devices | awk '/17d2/' RS=` terminal command

Comment: What is wrong with the internal Intel wifi card?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your remark. I was meaning to post the outcome from lsusb but opened the wrong document. I've edited the outpost to your command now.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the internal Intel wifi card on this computer (school pc), but it doesn't work on my home computer which is why I'm trying to get this adapter working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a driver for this dongle from the official repository.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Reboot and test the dongle.

If you do not have an internet connection without this dongle, you can install the driver offline this way:

Download these files using another computer:

[dkms](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6_all.deb)

[rtl8812au-dkms](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8812au/rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu1_all.deb)

Copy the files to your Home directory and run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtl8812au-dkms*.deb
```

Comment: Thank you! I installed the driver and the range has improved greatly now. Very much appreciated!