# How to install realtek wifi driver

Tags: drivers, realtek

I`m super new on Ubuntu, and I`m really lost with all the commands and etc...

I bought a USB wireless wi-fi adapter and it came with a cd with the driver (RTL 8821au).

The driver comes in a install.sh file.

After researching I managed in a way to run the .sh file in the terminal but after the process was done it showed me a message saying `compile make driver error: 2`

how can I install this driver properly? I need loads of help...

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASUS USB-AC56 (rtl8812au) WiFi Range issues](http://askubuntu.com/questions/736313/asus-usb-ac56-rtl8812au-wifi-range-issues)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

what the OS version?

I found on 17.10 :

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Comment: I read it wrong , rtl8812au is not rtl8821au